# Pycharm debugger "waiting for connections" but running still working

Tags: python, django, pycharm, dock

I am trying to debug django project with docker-compose interpreter.

Here is my pycharm configurations

[image: Pycharm configurations image]

But when I trying to debug it project still running but debugger is still waiting for connection and break point not working

[image: Debugger can't connect image]

I think that structure of my project have problem cause i'm try to debug other project it still working.

Here is my project structure

[image: Project structure image]

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To whomever else it might help, the problem in my case was that I attempted to use the debugger coupled with a run inside a Docker container functionality.

I also happened to have all ports published on that container which prevented the debugger to connect. Publishing only ports I actually needed, resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check the running ports on your machine. In my case, the port that PyCharm wanted to use for debugging (127.0.0.1:xxxx) was being used by another program on my laptop.

You can check the running ports using the following command on mac:

```
lsof -i -P | grep -i "listen"
```

Or, the following command once you know which port PyCharm is trying to use (usually you can see that on top of the console tab of PyCharm after starting debugging process):

```
sudo lsof -i :xxxxx
```

After running that, you should see a list with PID numbers, names of program etc. Then you can kill the running process on that port using the PID:

```
sudo kill -9 PID
```

Or, just restart your computer.

If that doesn't work, then it might be due to using already-existing Python module names. Make sure the names of the Python files in your project isn't the same as any other library/code from python.